# Find signals/events available for a Gtk+3 widget using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, gtk

I'm working with Gtk in Python and I am at a loss as to how to find out what events/signals are available for a widget.  Most tutorials will show how to use a "clicked" event, but are there more events/signals that are present to use for any particular widget? Is that it?

Where would I find a list of what is available to use for any particular widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the documentation page for the widget, here [`GtkButton`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html):

[image]

Clicking on the "signals" link will lead you to the list of signals available for that widget. If you don't find the signal you want, it may be implemented by a parent class, or in one of the implemented interfaces. The "object hierarchy" and "implemented interfaces" links will help you navigate among classes and interfaces and find the signals you need.

Comment: I've been in the same boat, and using [Glade](https://glade.gnome.org/) has been invaluable to the cause in finding what's available, and what's not. Adding a button, and checking its signals tab has helped me narrow down easily what is "triggerable". [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PyQBL.png)

Answer (score -1):

May seem like an obvious answer, but did you consider reading [the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/)?

Comment: Not so obvious if you're expecting to find documentation for the Python APIs! But unfortunately, yes, reading the C documentation is the best way.

Comment: @ptomato: Things are slowly [starting to change](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2014-February/msg00001.html) on this regard.

Comment: this not an answer while I have the same question, having :
`TypeError: <WebKit2.ContextMenuItem object at ...>: unknown signal name: activate`

nor [WebKit2 API](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/WebKit2-4.0/classes/ContextMenuItem.html), nor [documentation](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/signal.MenuItem.activate.html), nor [tutorials](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/objects.html#signals) helps me...